# Mule Secure Property Place holder

Tags: mule

I am experimenting with Mule's secure property place holder, I got end up with namespace issue

The error is:

```
Failed to read schema document 'http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/secure-property-placeholder/current/mule-secure-property-placeholder.xsd', because 
1) could not find the document; 
2) the document could not be read; 
3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

Can any please solve the issue?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

This may be very late answer but may be it helps in future for someone. This error comes due to multiple versions of secure property placeholder. Please check the versions installed and keep only updated one.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install this add-on in Anypoint Studio?
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/anypoint-enterprise-security

my complete schemaLocation is: 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/secure-property-placeholder http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/secure-property-placeholder/current/mule-secure-property-placeholder.xsd

Comment: That XSD is gone too.  Seems like the whole secure properties folder is missing.